# Strange SQLite problem testing if column was returned

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I guess the best thing to do is to show the code what I'm doing at the result:

This works:

```
if (sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)) {
    [marker setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)] forKey:@"id"];
}
```

This always returns false for the if statement:

```
if (sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)) {
    [marker setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)] forKey:@"id"];
}
```

This returns an incorrect result for the column:

```
if (sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)) {
    [marker setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] forKey:@"id"];
}
```

Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the number of columns returned before you try to access the value of the column.

```
int count = sqlite3_column_count (statement);
```

When you call sqlite3_column_int(), it returns the integer value of the column. What if that value is zero? You can't tell the difference between a valid zero result and a null value for that column. You can test if a column has a null with

```
sqlite3_column_type () == SQLITE_NULL;
```

Also, Obj-C does not automatically convert different types, so `numberWithInt: sqlite3_column_text` will of course give garbage results. What sqlite3_column_text() returns is a pointer to a C string, which is an address in memory where the string resides. I'm guessing you're expecting it to somehow convert the string to an integer? That doesn't happen in C.